# Logical error causing infinite while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

When the user enters the number 0 and the program does task0 the while loop does not end as I intended it to. Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
def task0():
    print("Goodbye")
    end = "true"
end = "false"
while end != "true":
    print()
    tasknum = input("Which task would you like to see? ")
    print()
    task = "task" + tasknum
    methodToCall = globals()[task]
    result = methodToCall()
```

Comment: you need to define `global end` inside task0

Comment: why aren't you using booleans (True, False)?

Comment: Also, please use a `list` of tasks instead of looking up variable variables in `globals`.

Answer (score 4):

It is best to communicate with your function by using return values, not altering global names.

Also, use `True` and `False`, there's no need to use string comparison.

In short, return `True` from your function and assign it to `end`:

```
def task0():
    print("Goodbye")
    return True

end = False
while not end:
    print()
    tasknum = input("Which task would you like to see? ")
    print()
    task = "task" + tasknum
    methodToCall = globals()[task]
    end = methodToCall()
```

you then check on that and end appropriately.

Comment: Also, as @tobias_k says in the comment above, it may be safer to use a list of valid tasks. `[task0, task1, ...]`

Comment: Safer in what sense @synchronizer? Peeking into and altering `globals` is perfectly safe. It is *completely* counter-intuitive and will cause confusion but, there's isn't any issue with safety here :-)